# Populate in mongoose returns array of _ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm creating simulation for goodreads by MERN stack
and when I'm using populate to retrieve books of specific user it returns empty array, I've done a lot of search but in vain
here's my model

```
const userSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
firstName:{
    type:"string",required:true
},
books:[{
    book:{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref:'Book'},rate:Number,shelve:''
}]});
```

And this is books model

```
const bookSchema =new mongoose.Schema({
title :{
    type:"string",required:true
}});
```

And this is how I use populate

```
router.get("/one", (req, res, next) => {
User.find({firstName : "John"}).populate("books.book").exec(function (err, user) { 
    res.json(user)
 });
})
```

and this is the resulted JSON

```
[{"_id":"5c70f299ef088c13a3ff3a2c","books":
[{"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310b9"},{"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310ba"},
 {"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310bb"},{"_id":"5c708c0077a0e703b15310bd"}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's an issue with how your `UserSchema` is defined. My assumption is that including the `rate` and `shelve` in the definition of `books` is causing the problem.

Try removing those fields to start, and just populating `books` instead of `books.book`. If that works, then I would really reconsider putting those fields where you have them. In my own personal opinion, I think they seem better in the `BookSchema` since each book in the `UserSchema` has a `rate` and `shelve` anyways. Hope this helps!!

Comment: i have tried that but nothing happened and when i use only books an empty array is returned